# How to send JSON to PHP through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've tried over and over and it never works. I don't know how to receive the JSON on the server side.

**JS**

```
function newReport_compilation(){
 ...
 return JSON.stringify(formData);
}
var formData = newReport_compilation(); //takes all values from my form
...
$("#newReport_submit").on('click',function(){
ajaxRequestTwo("databaseButler.php?reqType="+2, "text", formData, function(returnedData){
console.log(returnedData); //To test
...
}}

function ajaxRequestTwo(reqScript, returnDataType, reqData, callback){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: returnDataType,
        url: reqScript,
        data: {fData:reqData},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("AJAX request success.");
            callback(data);
        },
        fail: function(){
            console.log("AJAX request failed.");
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Error!");
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP (DatabaseButler.php)**

```
function reportInsert(){
    def();
    //Establish a new connection
    $repInsCon = new Db();
    //Run the insertReport function from the DB class (Send it the report ID & the JSON data of the submitted form)
    $result = $repInsCon->insertReport($_POST['fData']);
    echo $result;
}
if(isset($_GET['reqType'])){
    ...
    }else if($_GET['reqType']=="2"){
        reportInsert();
    }
}
```

**Deeper PHP (inside Db() class)**

```
public function insertReport($jsonForm){
$newRepData = json_decode($jsonForm,true);
echo $jsonForm;
... //I have the SQL INSERT query part commented out here but I can't get here regardless
    }
```

It gives me an error saying **Notice: Undefined index: fData in C:\wamp\www\HCSProjects\Pigeon\Main\databaseButler.php**

I don't understand how you receive the JSON data on the PHP side? What is the JSON called once it reaches PHP? How do I receive it properly on the server side?
:/

I've been looking into this for hours on end. There's no proper answer anywhere.

**UPDATE**
The AJAX request works fine because I get a 4 and a 200 on the response. 
The following line in the butler.php file is the problem: (I removed the reqType by the way.... i just made the url databaseButler.php with no additional parameters).

```
if(isset($_POST['req'])){
```

'req' in the above line is one my JSON values. I console.logged the JSON before I sent it to PHP. (My JSON is reqData. I console.logged formData which is the same thing)

{"id":"1615","na":"Y","ph":"905-525-9140","em":"h@mcmaster.ca","dep":"Residence Admissions","req":"PC Issues","cus":"","summ":"diwjdiwjdi","det":"","pri":"Low","dat":"07/08/2015","ti‌​m":"anytime"}

This is my newReport_compilation function by the way:

```
function newReport_compilation(){
    var formData = {id:hash(1),na:$("#newReport_name").val(),ph:$("#newReport_phone").val(),em:$("#newReport_email").val(),dep:$("#newReport_department").val(),req:$("#newReport_requestCategory").val(),cus:$("#newReport_otherRequest").val(),summ:$("#newReport_summary").val(),det:$("#newReport_details").val(),pri:$("input[type='radio'][name='priority']:checked").val(),dat:$("#newReport_date").val(),tim:$("#newReport_time").val()};
    return JSON.stringify(formData);
}
```

How do I get my JSON values on the PHP side? There's no help anywhere guys :/

**UPDATE: FOUND A SOLUTION**

For those interested:
The problem was the JSON.stringify(formData) in newReport compilation. Apparently you don't have to stringify formData if it was stored in JSON like form. It was like I tried to convert an already JSON string to JSON, which broke it.

Also, when you send data in both the URL and in JSON form, access everything using $_REQUEST and not $_POST or $_GET. However any JSON data you send over goes by the format you send the data. In my case I used POST. So to get ID or name or the server side (DatabaseButler PHP) you would use $_POST['id'] or $_POST['summ'].

Comment: sending POST....looking for GET ... won't get you very far

Comment: I used $_POST['fData'] though. What do you mean? @charlietfl

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_REQUEST)` in your reportInsert.php file and tell us what it has.

Comment: This is what I got: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  'reqType' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
</pre> @Bankzilla

Comment: I'm lost at what you're trying to do with `newReport_compliation()`, it's clear that you're `fdata` never makes it to the server side. If you actually `console.log(reqData)` before sending it, is the data there?

Comment: newReport_compilation just takes all the values from my form and puts it in a JSON like JS array which I then stringify and send back. Yep the data is there! I console.logged it after newReport_compilation returns it and i get: {"id":"1615","na":"Y","ph":"905-525-9140","em":"h@mcmaster.ca","dep":"Residence Admissions","req":"PC Issues","cus":"","summ":"diwjdiwjdi","det":"","pri":"Low","dat":"07/08/2015","tim":"anytime"}  @Bankzilla

Comment: That JSON stuff is the form data i entered. ID, Name, Phone, Email etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP request can be POST or GET but not both and your code is trying to access variables through `$_POST` and `$_GET`, and that is not OK.
I would suggest to use `$_REQUEST` instead and it will take care of it (if POST or GET).
Despite of using `type: "POST"`, jQuery will take it as a "GET" request because you are pointing to an URL with a querystring.

Comment: I tried using $_REQUEST['fData']. Still says it is undefined. :/

Comment: Do you think I should get rid of the reqData parameter in the URL of the AJAX request and put it in the JSON instead? @Mindastic

Comment: The request method doesn't really effect the PHP `$_POST` and `$_GET` super globals. You can POST `a=b` to `/url?foo=bar` and access `$_POST['a']` and `$_GET['foo']`

Comment: May be you can bypass the part of stringifying the json and send it as the data. For example data:reqData. Then, in your backend, you can get each property from the form. Also, you don't need to set the content type to the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

pass it as `JSON` instead of `text`:

```
ajaxRequestTwo("databaseButler.php?reqType=2", "json", formData, function(returnedData)
```

This will give you more debugging error:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

Comment: It prints out "Error!" from the ajax function. The original error is gone now. Nothing else has changed. :| @meda

Comment: what does the server return?

Comment: Nothing I guess? I didn't get anything back. If i did it would've console logged it

Comment: I got: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' then when i clicked on details in the chrome console log... i got ' Notice: Undefined index: fData in C:\wamp\www\HCSProjects\Pigeon\Main\databaseButler.php'

Comment: @MightyRevenge your question changed a lot now, where is the issue now

Comment: Okay so I verified that I'm sending the correct JSON (console.logged the JSON data before i sent it to PHP) so that works. All i get now is "Error!". I don't even get "AJAX request success." (refer the ajaxRequestTwo function) I'm clueless. @meda

Comment: @MightyRevenge add a response to your PHP script in JSON then it will fix

Answer (score 0):

You First Change

```
ajaxRequestTwo("databaseButler.php?reqType="+2, "**text**", formData, ....
```

To:

```
ajaxRequestTwo("databaseButler.php?reqType="+2, "json", formData, ....
```

---

You should set `datatype` to `json` no `text`!
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",...
});

in php you must Before Use $_GET or $_POST data,
  check if(isset($_POST['...'])) or if($_POST['...'])